# How do I make an OscillatorNode oscilate between 0 and 1 in Web Audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

To my understanding, all waves from the oscillator oscillate from -1 to 1.

I want to make them oscillate from 0 to 1, still using sine and square waves.

Why? for example a vibrato that only pitches up (pitch never goes below the main note, like a guitar vibrato).

In the vibrato case. the closest thing I got to was to play the note in the middle of the two notes and oscillate from there, but the tones aren't exactly right:

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = new AudioContext();

// notes are semitones from soundFreq
var soundFreq = 440; // a4
var mainNote = 0.0;  // a4
var bendNote = 4.0;  // c#4 (major third interval)

// nSoundSource is the sound we're playing, on the a4
var nSoundSource = audioContext.createOscillator();
nSoundSource.type = 'triangle';
nSoundSource.frequency.value = soundFreq; // a4

// at 1 second sound plays the note between a4 and c#4: b4
nSoundSource.frequency.setValueAtTime(
  intervalToFrequency((mainNote + bendNote) / 2) * soundFreq,
  audioContext.currentTime + 1.0
);

// at 3 seconds, sound returns to a4
nSoundSource.frequency.setValueAtTime(
  soundFreq,
  audioContext.currentTime + 3.0
);


// gain to change the detune of the played sound
var nGainSoundFreq = audioContext.createGain();

// if amplitude is the whole interval (400 cents), the value should be half of that, so in this case 200 cents
nGainSoundFreq.gain.value = ((mainNote + bendNote) / 2) * 100; // 200 cents up and down

// oscillator to make the vibrato on the gain
var nGainSoundFreqOsc = audioContext.createOscillator();
nGainSoundFreqOsc.type = 'square'; // try with sine too
nGainSoundFreqOsc.frequency.value = 3;
nGainSoundFreqOsc.start(audioContext.currentTime + 1.0);
nGainSoundFreqOsc.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 3.0);

// enable vibrato
nGainSoundFreqOsc.connect(nGainSoundFreq);
nGainSoundFreq.connect(nSoundSource.detune);

// play the sound
nSoundSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
nSoundSource.start(audioContext.currentTime);
nSoundSource.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 4.0);


// helper to convert semitones to frequency
function intervalToFrequency(interval) {
    return Math.pow(2, interval / 12);
}
```

I know I can achieve the vibrato using other techniques, that's not the point. I want to know if it is possible to make a NodeOscillator oscilate between 0 and 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO does not write code for you. We can help debug your code, or answer specific questions about how to code it.

Comment: I don't want anyone to write code for me.
I've been researching for 2 days, the documentation is poor, and there is no example of what I want on the internet.  
The closest thing I got to was to play the note in the middle of the two notes and oscillate from there, but the tones aren't exactly right.  
I haven't had luck using fourier series either so I figured there must be a better way.

Comment: Knowing the API in question, I'd say this question is fine. The OP has included what he/she has tried so far and the reasoning behind it. Including code would be pointless as this is a question of approach, not a specific bug. Considering the background given and the scope of the API, this question can't be considered too broad, or no web audio question besides bugs could ever be posted here.

Comment: I've edited the question to include code for a specific case, but I'm afraid the original meaning is lost. I don't want to solve this specific case. I want to oscillate between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square wave oscillator does go from -1 to 1, but not quite the way you expect because it is normalized.  Due to bandlimiting, there is some ringing which at the discontinuities, so the actual "square" top of the wave is slightly below 1.

You could add a gain to the output to scale it up a little.  The best solution is to use [PeriodicWave](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-periodicwave-interface) to create your own square wave but turn off this normalization.  Then the square top will have amplitude 1, but some parts of the wave will exceed 1.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to make the square wave go from 0 to 1, you can with a little bit of work.  You can use a WaveShaperNode to do this.  Or you a bit more intuitively, create an AudioBufferSource with a constant output of 1 and connect both your oscillator and the source to a gain node with a gain of 1/2.  The gain node will sum the oscillator and the source to shift everything up, and the 1/2 gain scales it to [0,1]

Comment: Thanks, I even thought it might have been a bug. About the oscillator not hitting exactly +1, I found out that instead of multiplying the note by 100 cents, 118 works perfectly. I can't tell a difference if I oscillate 2 octaves.